# getline with delimiter

Tags: c++, string, loops, io, getline

What's the proper way to loop with `getline` on fixed array? The following loop will stop if delimiter isn't found in the block of read characters.

```
char data[4];
while (cin.getline(data, 4, '.'))
{
  ...
}
```

Sample data that will cause the loop to fail:

```
asdasdasdasd.asdasdasd
```

Answer (score 3):

*"What's the proper way to loop with `getline` on fixed array?"*

- step 1: don't use C-style `char` array
- step 2: don't rely on the input having mercy on your program

Possible solution:

```
std::string token;
while (std::getline(std::cin, token, '.')) {
    if (token.empty()) {
        // TODO
        continue; // ?
    }
    if (token.size() == 4) {
        // TODO
    }
    else {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't ask the question if I didn't want to use the C-style char array.

Comment: @SebastianNowak: Then initialize your `char` array using the contents of `std::string` object, just make sure it is big enough.

Comment: @SebastianNowak Which leads to the obvious question: *why*?